# Creating std::vector<Class> with calling Class constructor later on

Tags: c++, stdvector

I've been googling and stackoverflowing this question, but couldn't find any answer.

The thing I am trying to do is create a vector with a custom class, which I have no problem with. I understand I need to do:

```
std::vector<ExtClass> varName;
```

But, what I want to do is this:

Since varName is now of type ExtClass, I want to call it's constructor in another class. To clarify, I think the code will explain this the best:

```
class ExtClass {
    public:
        int ext;
        int pet;

    ExtClass();
};

ExtClass:ExtClass() {
    this->ext = std::rand();
    this->pet = std::rand();
}

________________________

class MainClass {
    public:
        std::vector<ExtClass> attribute;

    MainClass(int);
}

MainClass(int size) {
    this->attribute.reserve(size) // reserving enough places in vector
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        this->attribute[i] = new ExtClass(); // problem
}
```

I have used all public members to avoid unnecessary code.

I thought since std::vector attribute is a vector of ExtClass elements, and since none have been defined, that I could assign each element of the vector as:

```
new ExtClass()
```

and that would create, for example:

```
attribute[0].ext = 5125;
attribute[0].pet = 151;
```

This is definitely not the case and the compiler argues on this line with:

```
note: candidate: constexpr ExtClass& ExtClass::operator=(const ExtClass&)
class ExtClass {
      ^~~~~~
note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘ExtClass*’ to ‘const ExtClass&’
note: candidate: constexpr ExtClass& ExtClass::operator=(ExtClass&&)
note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘ExtClass*’ to ‘ExtClass&&’
```

I am not an expert in C++, but relatively new to it and I am practicing. Can you tell me what is my mistake? What assumption did I make wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: `reserve` != `resize`.

Comment: No new needed BTW.

Comment: Your vector is defined to hold objects of type `ExtClass` but you are trying to push pointers there. You either need to have vector of smart pointers or redesign your approach

Comment: Use `push_back` or `emplace_back`. It's very important to know the difference between a pointer to an object and an object itself (`Object*` and `Object`) in C++.

Comment: This use of `new` shows an influence from languages like Java. You don't need to `new` every single object in C++. In fact, you should not use it at all (outside of very specific use cases) in modern code. Only use dynamic allocation when you *really* need it, and then prefer `std::make_unique` or `std::make_shared` instead of `new`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Code as written can be fixed by this:

```
MainClass(int size) 
   : attribute( size )
{
}
```

that's it it will initialize `attribute` with `size` default constructed objects of `ExtClass`.

Note that this code:

```
this->attribute.reserve(size) // reserving enough places in vector
for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    this->attribute[i] = new ExtClass(); // problem
```

even if we fix it to be compilable:

```
this->attribute.reserve(size) // reserving enough places in vector
for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    this->attribute[i] = ExtClass(); // problem
```

leads to UB as you try to access elements of empty vector - calling reserve does not change how many objects vector holds, only capacity for future use.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I though it was clear by my remark, anyway changed it to be more clear

Comment: Thanks for the help! :)
Honestly, these two make more sense to me, although I do not understand the first one at all. Google it is! :)

Comment: @Amaterastis it is called member initializer list, you can find some details for example here https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/when-do-we-use-initializer-list-in-c/

Comment: Thanks once again! :)

Comment: @Amaterastis More on the [member initializer list](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list). It is one of the most useful and least taught pieces of C++ syntax out there. Not only does it make constructors easier to write (and often faster to run), but there's a lot of code that you simply cannot write without it.

Answer (score 2):

As the comments above indicate, you can replace:

```
for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    this->attribute[i] = new ExtClass();
```

with:

```
for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    this->attribute.emplace_back ();
```

Your vector will then manage the lifetimes of your `ExtClass` objects for you.

Comment: Thanks for the help! :) It works! I'll check more details about that method. :)